# Loading a URL in a webview window

Tags: android, url, webview

I am trying to create my first android app, so please go easy!

I want a webview window to load a url but can't find how to do it, I have the webview window in my layout but cant find where to put the url it should load from.

I also want to have some buttons at the bottom which when pressed loads a different url in the webview.

Can anyone help please, this is very confusing :)

Thanks in advance

Jay

Comment: Please post some code. What have you done so far?

Comment: so far I just have this:

Comment: sorry it wont let me post it, too long

Answer (score 1):

I could easely give you some code but will rather point you in the right direction. You want to change your main.xml to use relativelayout instead of linearlayout. Then you want to add some buttons bellow at the bottom in your relative layout and add the webview above your buttons (the buttons could be put inside a linearlayout). In code after you set your contentview you then use findviewbyid(R.id.idofyourwebview) and then you look at the webview documentation to use the right method for loading the url. Also remember to update the manifest to allow internet access or it wont work.

Comment: That all went straight over my head but I would rather learn than have it done for me, how do I change to relativelayout? this is the first time I have even tried to make an android app so don't know my way around it as yet.

Comment: If you are at that stage I'd recommend starting with the google hello tutorial and then continue to the google views tutorials then you would have a better idea of what I'm talking about. Also use google to search for your answers.

Comment: ok thanks for your help, I have found out how to change the layout I will see if I can find some examples.